# Is there a way to allow users to upload files to google cloud storage without app engine(PHP)?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I could be able to upload the file from my server using the cloud storage php API(objects->insert).
Is there a way to do the same from the user end to the Google cloud storage using the same? or only App Engine is best available way?

Answer (score 3):

Users can upload files [directly to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload). There is no need to go through your App Engine instance.

Edit 2021:

New documentation for uploading files to Google Cloud Storage:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-php

Comment: Thanks for response Volgin. But, in that case I need to make use of the app engine api.

Comment: Hey I am new bee to the Google cloud and am trying to implement the file upload feature using cloud storage API. Currently, I am not using any AppEngine SDK in my project. So, is there any way to implement the same using Cloud storage API(https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Comment: The library that you linked to includes examples for simple file upload and large file upload. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry for testing ur patience Volgin. The thing is, to enable users to upload the files I need to create a upload url. But, using the above [mentioned library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) I am unable to create upload url since there is no CloudStorageTools class.

Comment: I am using [this API](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Storage.php)

Comment: "This solution is no longer recommended"

Comment: @zabop - The library changed, but you can still upload directly to the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but since one of the few Google results for how to do this is that php example, thought I'd answer this. You can generate a signed link without the App Engine API, as [detailed here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program), but since "you must have an OAuth client ID and private keys for a service account type application" you'd need to do it from a server (or Cloud Function) that you control rather than 'from the user end'.